# In windows cmd, how to know if this terminal is launched with "Run as administrator"

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I was writing some script which requires `Run as administrator`, if not , script should tell user to do so and exit.

But I didn't find how to get this test, `whoami` command returns same result whether you start cmd as or not with `Run as admin`

Comment: @John yes, command will say no enough permission and exit, but I want to give user active hint before that happen and gracefully exit my own script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44100707/11262439 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051883/batch-script-how-to-check-for-admin-rights

Comment: @BlindSpots the logfile one is great, love that, than you!

Comment: you can do `command that requires admin > nul` and then check `%errorlevel%` to see if the last command was succesful or not.